# Cant connect to Azure DB from Azure web application

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-roles

I am trying to set up a new azure website. I have done this before and everything just worked, this time I'm having real trouble getting the database set up.

I setup both site and database in the deploy wizard, and have a connection string named the same as on my local box. The error I'm getting is below:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

If i copy paste the connection string from azure to my local box (and add my local ip to the whitelist for SqlAzure) then it works fine locally (which is why I'm a little stumped)

The only thing that that I have noticed is that if I download the web.config for the site as configured in azure there are no connection strings. I imagine that this is because they are doing some clever security thing.

Any idea what I can even try next to diagnose this?

Comment: What kind of site is it? Orchard, wordpress? When you say you copy the connection string from Azure to your local box it works, but then you say the web.config for the site doesn't have a connection string in it. Where are you getting the one that works?

Comment: @mikewo its a custom mvc site which uses EF. In azure there is a section where you manage connection strings, I copied that connection string to my local dev box and it works, however if I FTP to the azure site and look at the web.config the CS isn't there (even though its configured in the azure portal).

Comment: Ugh this just suddenly started working, no idea why but i suppose its fixed?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor You can monitor failed connections/throttled SQL Azure DB connections in the Azure portal ( I think there are tables that you can query as well to get that information from t-sql).